# Euclidean TSP and NN heuristic. Approximation ratio?

Tags: algorithms

Consider the TSP problem, in the symmetric and euclidean case. Consider the nearest neighbor heuristic. Is the approximation ratio some given constant? Can the approximation be made arbitrarily bad?

The worst example I can think of with pen and paper has an approximation rate of $\frac{3}{2}$, I am not sure if this can be made worse or not.

Comment: Can we assume that the triangle-inequality holds ? In this case, if I remember right, the approximation is at most twice the optimum.

Comment: Yes, with euclidean I mean that the "cities" are on a plane and the distance is the euclidean distance.

Comment: I am not sure whether the nearest neighbor heuristic gives at most twice the optimum, I only remember that in this case there is a polynomial algorithm with this bound.

Comment: This should provide you with an answer: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/approximation-for-metric-tsp-worst-case-using-nearest-neighbor-heuristic